# Yii2 List View: how to generate 2 different parent div to seprate odd and even records

Tags: listview, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need Yii2 `ListView` to generate 2 different parent div with items like:

```
<div class="odd">
    <items>item1</items>
    <items>item3</items>
    <items>item5</items>
    <items>item7</items>
</div>

<div class="even">
    <items>item2</items>
    <items>item4</items>    
    <items>item6</items>
    <items>item8</items>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what have you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may extend `ListView` class like this:

```
class ListViewOdd extends ListView
{
    public function renderItems()
    {
        $models = $this->dataProvider->getModels();
        $keys = $this->dataProvider->getKeys();
        $rowsOdd = $rowsEven = [];
        foreach (array_values($models) as $index => $model) {
            if ($index%2 == 0) {
                 $rowsOdd[] = $this->renderItem($model, $keys[$index], $index);
            } else {
                 $rowsEven[] = $this->renderItem($model, $keys[$index], $index);
            }
        }
        return '<div class="odd">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsOdd) . '</div><div class="even">'.implode($this->separator, $rowsOdd) .'</div>'; // replace <div> to Html::tag('div', ...)
    }
}
```

Output widget:

```
echo ListViewOdd::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_post',       
]);
```

Comment: Great Solution i tried this and fixed my problem. Really Appreciate